Need to remove mokutil from Ubuntu 22.04 install in order to install Windows again and then dual boot
I'm trying to remove Ubuntu 22.04, install Windows 11 and then reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 as a dual boot. I was trying to use Windows in VirtualBox which made me install mokutil. VirtualBox is too slow to run CAD well, so I'm dual booting.
I keep getting blocked from installing Windows due to EFI security.
I ran:
sudo mokutil --export sudo mokutil --delete file.der

When I try to delete key on reboot I get Failed to retrieve moklist. I can't find an answer.
I have tried to remove mokutil keys and tried disabling Secure Boot. I have also tried restoring the BIOS to its factory settings.
